# Does WdlResamplingSampleProvider work with 32 bit?

Tags: naudio

I can get WdlResamplingSampleProvider to work for the 16 bit example provided by Mark Heath on his blog;

```
int outRate = 16000;
var inFile = @"test.mp3";
var outFile = @"test resampled WDL.wav";
using (var reader = new AudioFileReader(inFile))
{
    var resampler = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(reader, outRate);
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outFile, resampler);
}
```

except I'm reading a wav file instead of an mp3 file. But I really need to work with 32 bit wav files (input and output) without losing bit depth. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`WdlResamplingSampleProvider` works with 32 bit floating point (IEEE) samples. So `AudioFileReader` has already converted to 32 bit float if the input wasn't like that. So it's completely up to you what you do with the output. If you just call `CreateWaveFile` you'll get a 32 bit floating point WAV file.

Comment: If I call CreateWaveFile instead of CreateWaveFile16 I get the following error; Unable to cast object of type 'NAudio.WaveSampleProviders.WdlResamplingSampleProvider' to type 'NAudio.Wave.IWaveProvider'.

Comment: there's a SampleToWaveprovider you can use

Comment: I tried to figure out how to do this by myself, but no luck. Once I read a wave file in with the AudioFileReader how do I use SampleToWaveProvider to get CreateWaveFile to work? Do I use it before or after WdlResamplingSampleProvider?

Comment: Pass the WdlResampleSampleProvider into a SampleToWaveProvider, then pass that into CreateWaveFile

Comment: Great, thanks, it works. Somehow I got SampleToWaveProvider mixed up with WaveToSampleProvider and didn't notice.